# Disable NSTask Screenshot sound

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I am developing a screenshot app and I use NSTask to take the screenshot, But when app take screenshot Mac OSX default screenshout sound will be played.

```
let theProcess = NSTask()
theProcess.launchPath = "/usr/sbin/screencapture"
theProcess.arguments = ["/Users/profile/Desktop/111.png"]
theProcess.launch()
```

How can I disable it just for the current task and not generally in the mac osx.

Or It's good if I be able to change the sound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the `-x` argument to the command:

```
theProcess.arguments = ["-x", "/Users/profile/Desktop/111.png"]
```

More options available by running `screencapture --help`.

Comment: Wow, Great :) Thank you so much